# hudson: how to edit template?

Tags: hudson

I want to add my own text and change the template of the default hudson for authenticated users.

where are the html files located so I can edit them ? or is there another solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the war directory, after you started Hudson for the first time. There you should find all the components that are used (css, images, and scripts). Have fun changing them.

However, I would expect that your changes will be gone after you upgrade your Hudson server. You might be able to get around this problem by writing your own plugin.

Let us know, if you get it done and what the solution is.

Comment: where is the war directory ? are you talking about the .war file ? if so, how do you extract it, edit the layouts, and repackage it ?

Comment: you need to describe your installation a little bit more. There are two basic ways to run Hudson. 1. you can run it as stand alone. Than you will find the war folder in the same directory than the war itself. 2. It was deployed to an app server. In this case it depends on the app server where it explodes the war file. -- In general, a war file, like a jar or an ear file, just a zip file. It needs to follow certain conventions regarding the contend, but that is all. So you can (rename and) unpack it and look at the files. When you are done, you can zip it (and rename it back to a war file).